# Sending information from one Thread to another Thread in Python and displaying message in original Thread, PyQT, MVC architecture

Tags: python, multithreading, model-view-controller, pyqt5

I'm working on an example application in Python following an MVC architecture with PyQT5 as my user-interface. In this sample application, I have a countdown timer that runs in a thread and updates the progress bar while the thread is active. However, midway through the countdown timer, I wish to display a message box, but the issue is that the message box won't show up if I call it from the thread, so the program hangs up indefinitely. I've pasted the code for the application below. What's a better way of handling this and sending the thread information to the original thread so I can display the message box ?

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

import threading


class ExampleGUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample Application')
        # Set some main window's properties
        self.setFixedSize(235, 235)
        # Set the central widget and the general layout
        self.generalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self._centralWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self._centralWidget)
        self._centralWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        # Create the display and the buttons
        self._createDisplay()
        self._createButtons()

    def _createDisplay(self):
        """Create the display."""
        # Create the display widget
        self.display = QLineEdit()
        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
        # Set some display's properties
        self.display.setFixedHeight(35)
        self.display.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
        self.display.setReadOnly(True)
        # Add the display to the general layout
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.display)
        self.generalLayout.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

    def _createButtons(self):
        """Create the buttons."""
        buttonsLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.button1 = QPushButton("Start")
        self.button1.setFixedSize(80, 40)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Clear")
        self.button2.setFixedSize(80, 40)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        buttonsLayout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.generalLayout.addLayout(buttonsLayout)

    def setDisplayText(self, text):
        """Set display's text."""
        self.display.setText(text)
        self.display.setFocus()

    def clearDisplay(self):
        """Clear the display."""
        self.setDisplayText("")

    def msgBox(self, text):
        msg_box = QMessageBox()
        msg_box.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        msg_box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msg_box.setText(text)
        msg_box.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Cancel)

        ret_val = msg_box.exec_()
        if ret_val == QMessageBox.Ok:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = ''
        self.i = ''

    def countdown(self, counter):
        self.i = 0
        self.counter = counter
        while self.i < self.counter:
            self.i+=1
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.i == 5:
                user_clicked = yield("Please click okay to continue")
                if user_clicked is False:
                    raise StopIteration


class Controller:
    def __init__(self, view, model):
        self._view = view
        self._model = model
        self._connect_settings_signals()

    def _set_message(self):
        self._view.progress_bar.setMaximum(10)
        x = threading.Thread(target=self._start_countdown, args=(10,))
        x.start()
        while x.is_alive():
            self._view.progress_bar.setValue(self._model.i)
        x.join()
        self._view.setDisplayText("Countdown complete!")

    def _start_countdown(self, count):
        coroutine = self._model.countdown(count)
        val = coroutine.__next__()
        while val is not None:
            print(val)
            reply = self._view.msgBox(val)
            if reply is False:
                coroutine.send(False)
            val = coroutine.__next__()

    def _clear_message(self):
        self._view.progress_bar.setValue(0)
        self._view.clearDisplay()

    def _connect_settings_signals(self):
        self._view.button1.clicked.connect(self._set_message)
        self._view.button2.clicked.connect(self._clear_message)


def main():
    """Main function."""
    # Create an instance of `QApplication`
    pycalc = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Show the calculator's GUI
    view = ExampleGUI()
    view.show()
    model = Model()
    # Create instances of the model and the controller
    ctrl = Controller(view=view, model=model)
    # Execute calculator's main loop
    sys.exit(pycalc.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Any level of access to GUI elements of Qt should always happen within the main Qt thread. To achieve that, it's better to use QThreads instead of python threads, and use signals/slots to interact with GUI elements.

Comment: Why do you need a thread to make a timer? You should use QTimer.

Comment: This is just a sample application. In my actual application, I have a lot going on in that method.